# Previous insertions in an array of linked list is being replaced by the most recent insertion

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I am trying to create an array of linked list, which stores names in the index location provided by the hash value of the name.

For some reason, all the previous insertion is replaced by the most recent insertion.

```
struct Node{
    char *key;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct Table{
    struct Node **entrypoint;
};
```

```
void InsertData(struct Table* table, const char *const name){

    //char dest[100];

    //strncpy(dest, name, 50);

    int hashIndex = HashVal(name);

    printf("Index Value is %d\n", hashIndex);


    struct Node *new_node;

    new_node = (struct Node* )malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->key = (char *)malloc((strlen(name)+1)*sizeof(char));

    if(table->entrypoint[hashIndex] == 0){ 
        table->entrypoint[hashIndex] = new_node;
        strcpy(new_node->key, name);
        new_node->next = NULL;
    }

    else{
        struct Node *cursor = table->entrypoint[hashIndex];
        while(cursor->next  != NULL)
            cursor = cursor->next;

    cursor->next = new_node;
        strcpy(new_node->key, name);
        new_node->next = NULL;
    }


    //DISPLAY LIST
    //int count = 0;
    struct Node *temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){

        if(table->entrypoint[i] == NULL)
            printf("%d: \n", i);
        else{
            temp = table->entrypoint[i];
            printf("%d: ", i);
            printf("%s ", temp->key);
            //count = 0;

                         while(temp->next != NULL){
                printf("%s ", temp->key);
                temp = temp->next;
                count++;
            }
            //printf("No. of times ran: %d", count);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

}
```

The number of Nodes created and their position in the linked list is working fine.

But all the insertions are getting replaced by the final insertion

**Expected Result:**

```
InsertData(&table, "Jeffrey Lars");
InsertData(&table, "Neal Rhine");
InsertData(&table, "Ledley King");

Table:
0: 
1: 
2: 
3: Jeffrey Lars, Ledley King
4:
5:
6:
7:
8:
9:
10:
11:
12:
13:
14: Neal Rhine
```

**Actual Result:**

```
InsertData(&table, "Jeffrey Lars");
InsertData(&table, "Neal Rhine");
InsertData(&table, "Ledley King");

Table:
0: 
1: 
2: 
3: Ledley King, Ledley King
4:
5:
6:
7:
8:
9:
10:
11:
12:
13:
14: Ledley King
```

Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: worse than just that; when `InsertData` returns the node you added has a pointer to string data that is officially *dangling*. That is to say, it *used to* point to valid data, but upon return the buffer `dest` referenced is no longer valid, and your program will invoke UB if it tries to chase those pointers. I think more time better understanding dynamic memory management, and how pointers in C work, should probably be on the menu.

Comment: I got rid of the `dest`. And used `strcpy(new_node->key, name)` after allocating memory to new_node->key using `new_node->key = (char *)malloc((strlen(name)+1)*sizeof(char));`. Still seems to have the same problem as before

Comment: Where is your code to allocate the memory for the entrypoint ?